# Use apply() in R to automate drawing specific row values from a matrix and do matrix operations

Tags: r, function, matrix, apply

I have two matrices.
Matrix A with variables x, y, a binary variable t1, and row numbers (row1, row2,....) that have values that correspond to rows in Matrix B.
Matrix B has two columns with values that correspond to the x, y variables in Matrix A.

I want to multiply each row of matrix A with values drawn from matrix B for every value of row1 and row2, find the sum and multiply it with the row value from column t1 of matrix A.

Matrix A

| x | y | t1 | row1 | row2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 5 |

Matrix B

| Rand_x | Rand_y |
| --- | --- |
| 0.01 | 0.252 |
| 0.78 | -0.12 |
| -0.77 | 0.004 |
| -0.97 | 0.04 |
| 0.17 | 0.104 |

The row-wise operation would look something like this. The final output would be M, a 3x1 matrix.

([1 2] %*% t([0.01 0.252]) + [1 2] %*% t([0.78 -0.12]))*1 = 1.054

([3 4] %*% t([-0.97 0.04]) + [1 2] %*% t([0.17 0.104]))*1 = -0.512

([2 2] %*% t([-0.97 0.04]) + [1 2] %*% t([0.17 0.104]))*0 = 0

Matrix M

| M |
| --- |
| 1.054 |
| -0.512 |
| 0 |

I initially used for loops to loop over each matrix row and the values of row1, row 2, row 3..... Unfortunately for large matrices, computation time is in several minues (sometimes even hours). I would like to use apply() function to speed this.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

I am new to R and stackoverflow. I apologize if my explanation was not clear.

Answer (score 2):

The figures in your example don't look right, so you might need to change it a bit, but here is how to do it (or at least something similar) with `apply`...

```
apply(mat_A, 1, function(x) (x[1:2] %*% mat_B[x[4],] +
                             x[1:2] %*% mat_B[x[5],]) * x[3])

[1]  1.054 -1.824  0.000
```

The function operates on each row of `mat_A`. Note that I think you want `%*%` for matrix multiplication, rather than `%%` for modulo, and to drop the `t()` transpose.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. This is exactly what I was looking for. This works well for two columns (row1 and row2). How do I automate this over n columns (row1, row2, row3, . . . rown). Thanks again.

Comment: @DiTe This will work for any number of rows of mat_A, but it only uses the five columns you specify, and depends on mat_B being large enough. I'm not sure why (or how) you would automate a different number of columns, as your formula only uses five.

Comment: I was able to automate the operation over n rows. I had to use for loop but it should work for the data size I am working with. 

I was not able to communicate the problem more clearly, initially. Thanks again for the help.

mat_A<-matrix(c(1,3,2,2,4,2,1,1,0,1,4,4,2,5,5), byrow = FALSE, 3,5)
mat_B<-matrix(c(0.01,0.78,-0.77,-0.97,0.17,0.252,-0.12,0.004,0.04,0.104), byrow=FALSE,5,2)

sum<-0
for (i in c(4:5))
  {
  sum<-sum+apply(mat_A, 1, function(x) (x[1:2] %*% mat_B[x[i],])* x[3])
  }

sum